# cant reach asp.net page on other server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, tcp, dns

I have defined an asp.net mvc app on server x. I added the sitename in the hostfile:

```
127.0.0.1   weeral.com
```

Also in IIS 7 i have added this as a sitebinding hostname weeral.com

When I hit http://weeral.com it responds find on the server.

However when I ping weeral.com from a different machine in the network it goes:

```
Ping request could not find host weeral.com. Please check the name...
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different machine doesn't have the same host file.

You need to map 127.0.0.1 to weeral.com on every one of the machines you use. If you used Dropbox (or something similar) you could symbolically link the machine's host file to the one in your Dropbox. I've done this for other config files, so I would think it would work for the host file.